# How to prevent jquery submit button from refreshing the HTML page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a login page where the user enters his username and password, when he submits this form the data is sent to php file for verifying the password.
For the first time when the user enters data (I entered wrong details) the page shows "Invalid password...please try again".

The second time when the user enters data (again I enter wrong details) the page just reloads. I am not able to understand why this is happening.
For more better understanding I have added a google drive link to a video showing the issue.

Link:[Link to the video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WfTf4YUT2cMnCM21dTtuFrAAjwnWC0K5)

The html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:justify-content="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 ">
<title>RVPS Elections</title>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark padding ">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
        <img src="assets/rv.png">
        RV PUBLIC SCHOOL
    </a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="admin.html">Admin Login</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
<p align="center" class="lead">Get administrator access by entering correct details</p>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid padding mt-1 " style="align-items: center;  justify-content:center; display:flex ;" >
<div class="row padding">
    <div class="card border-dark" >
        <div class="card-header" align="center">
            <img src="assets/rv.png">
            <h5>Admin Sign In</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body" id="admin-signin-card">
            <form id="admin-signin">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input id="admin_username" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter your username" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input id="admin_password" type="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter your Password" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <a href="#" class="text-primary">Forgot Password?</a>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" >
                    <input id="submit_button" type="submit" name="Sign In" value="Sign In" class="btn btn-success input-lg">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<footer>
<div class="container-fluid padding">
    <h1  align="center">About Us</h1>
    <p align="center">I am Goutam B Seervi. A student of RVPS for the year 2015-18</p>
    <h2 align="center">Contact me</h2>
    <p align="center">Phone nnumber : 7019271367</p>
    <p align="center">Email id : goutambseervi@gmail.com</p>
</div>
</footer>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/admin_login_script.js"></script>
</html>
```

The javascript part:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#admin-signin").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let admin_username = $("#admin_username").val();
        let admin_password = $("#admin_password").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php_admin_login.php',
            data: {
                admin_username: admin_username,
                admin_password: admin_password
            },
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                if (response === "OK") {
                    window.open("admin.html", "_self");
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('admin-signin-card').innerHTML += '<div class="alert alert-danger"><h5>Error occured...Please try again</h5></div>';
                    console.log("error shown");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I'm sure there is no problem with the php code so I'm not pasting here just to make the question more clearer.
If you need the whole code of the project you can get it here:[Github link to the project](https://github.com/Goutam192002/RVPS_Elections)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    else {
        document.getElementById('admin-signin-card').innerHTML += '<div class="alert …>';
```

*Adding* to an element’s `.innerHTML` replaces the whole content of the element; even the stuff that was already there will first be removed, and then re-created.

So your form itself is replaced with a new form, and therefor you completely lose your submit event handler you had attached to it as well.

Your attempts at preventing the default event action fail, because you handler function simply doesn’t get called any more at all, and just a normal form submit is performed now, which of course reloads the page.

You need to either add your event handler again after you replaced the parent container’s innerHTML - or use *event delegation* to begin with.

Comment: You could also put the error and give it `display: none;` and then just show it when the credentials are wrong.

Comment: I think what he may be looking for is `$("#admin-signin-card-error").append( new content );` ? ... or more simpler as Bojan said: just toggle an already made alert div on/off with `.show()` and `.hide()`.

Comment: thanks everyone it worked.The problem was correctly pointed out by CBroe.. i tried both the methods append() and display toggle..both worked

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this. Hope it will help

```
 $("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Kindly let me know if it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try `return false` at the end of your `$("#admin-signin").submit` function instead of the `preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to how you handle errors. By using `document.getElementById('admin-signin-card').innerHTML += ...` you are effectively reloading your form meaning that you lose the event listener. You can either adjust how you display the error or adjust the event listener.

I would recommend changing how you display the error.

I have removed the request in the example below but it's the same idea:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#admin-signin").submit(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   let admin_username = $("#admin_username").val();
   let admin_password = $("#admin_password").val();
   let response = "no";
   if (response === "OK") {
    window.open("admin.html", "_self");
   } else {
    document.getElementById('admin-signin-card-error').innerHTML ='<div class="alert alert-danger"><h5>Error occured...Please try again</h5></div>';
    console.log("error shown");
   }
  });
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:justify-content="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 ">
  <title>RVPS Elections</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark padding ">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
        <img src="assets/rv.png"> RV PUBLIC SCHOOL
      </a>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="admin.html">Admin Login</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <p align="center" class="lead">Get administrator access by entering correct details</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid padding mt-1 " style="align-items: center;  justify-content:center; display:flex ;">
    <div class="row padding">
      <div class="card border-dark">
        <div class="card-header" align="center">
          <img src="assets/rv.png">
          <h5>Admin Sign In</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body" id="admin-signin-card">
          <form id="admin-signin">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Username</label>
              <input id="admin_username" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter your username" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Password</label>
              <input id="admin_password" type="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter your Password" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <a href="#" class="text-primary">Forgot Password?</a>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input id="submit_button" type="submit" name="Sign In" value="Sign In" class="btn btn-success input-lg">
            </div>
          </form>
          <div id="admin-signin-card-error"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <div class="container-fluid padding">
      <h1 align="center">About Us</h1>
      <p align="center">I am Goutam B Seervi. A student of RVPS for the year 2015-18</p>
      <h2 align="center">Contact me</h2>
      <p align="center">Phone nnumber : 7019271367</p>
      <p align="center">Email id : goutambseervi@gmail.com</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

like @CBroe mentioned, the problem is caused by innerHTML.

i moved the content of innerHTML to the form, and give it display none, when there an error i show the error with .show()

i changed the ajax url and data Type for testing purpose.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#admin-signin").on('submit', function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        let admin_username = $("#admin_username").val();
        let admin_password = $("#admin_password").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://jsonp.afeld.me/?url=https://jsonview.com/example.json',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
                admin_username: admin_username,
                admin_password: admin_password
            },
            success: function (response) {
            
                if (response === "OK") {

                    window.open("admin.html", "_self");

                } else {

                    $('.alert.alert-danger').show();
                    
                    console.log("error shown");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:justify-content="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 ">
<title>RVPS Elections</title>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid padding mt-1 " style="align-items: center;  justify-content:center; display:flex ;" >
<div class="row padding">
    <div class="card border-dark" >
        <div class="card-header" align="center">
            <h5>Admin Sign In</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body" id="admin-signin-card">
            <form id="admin-signin">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input id="admin_username" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter your username" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input id="admin_password" type="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter your Password" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <a href="#" class="text-primary">Forgot Password?</a>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" >
                    <input id="submit_button" type="submit" name="Sign In" value="Sign In" class="btn btn-success input-lg">
                </div>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" style="display: none;"><h5>Error occured...Please try again</h5></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```